# Vectorized string processing in a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

How can i process  text in numpy arrays elegantly?

I can always iterate over the array, but is there some magic oneliner also possible?
I am just learning python and want to do it in a way that looks good also.

example of what i want:

```
for y in data['filename']:
first = 12
last  = y[1][12:].find('.')
y= y[1][first+1:last+12]
```

Comment: NumPy isn't for string processing. In fact, it's very inefficient at storing variable-length strings. You might want to do this in pure Python instead.

Comment: actually, is it even possible to store variable-length strings ?

Comment: @François - As an object array, yes.  (Though, at that point, you're better off with a list.)

Comment: @tarrasch - Have a look at `os.path.splitext` if you're trying to strip the extension off of filenames.  (Similarly, have a look at all of `os.path` if you're dealing with filenames/paths.)  As larsmans suggested, for dealing with strings in numpy arrays, just treat them like they were lists and iterate through.  `numpy` deliberately doesn't provide vectorized string operations.

Comment: @tarrasch did you check the answers below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `numpy.char.array()`, for example:

```
from string import find

import numpy as np

a = np.char.array(['cmd.py', 'matrix.txt', 'print.txt', 'test.txt', 'testpickle.test', 'Thumbs.db', 'tmp.py', 'tmp.txt', 'tmp2.py'])
find(a, '.py')
#array([ 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  3, -1,  4])


np.char.array(a.split('.'))[:,0]
#chararray(['cmd', 'matrix', 'print', 'test', 'testpickle', 'Thumbs', 'tmp', 'tmp', 'tmp2'], dtype='|S10')
```